# Replicating actionbar embedded tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have designed an app, that replicates the way Android embeds tabs in the actionbar, when there is room for it. In the two images below, you can see how the bottom part is in two panes in portrait mode, and becomes one single pane in landscape mode.

[image: Non-embedded]

[image: Embedded]

**What I want to do:**
Change to single pane layout whenever the actionbar changes to embedded mode, and to the two pane layout when the actionbar is not in embedded mode.

**What I have done so far:**
Put the two pane mode in the "layout"-folder and the single pane mode in the "layout-land"-folder. However, I am not quite sure, that this will replicate the actionbar behaviour. I would imagine, that big screen devices would show the embedded mode even when in portrait mode.

So, does anyone know exactly which parameters change the actionbar from non-embedded to embedded, and whether this could be fixed simply by adding some other qualifiers to the layout-folders name?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs is that a solution?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, that I understand? I am already using the actionbar tabs at the top, but I want to replicate the behaviour at the bottom as well.

Comment: My bad for inattentive reading, excuse me.

Comment: You wrote: 'I want to replicate the behaviour at the bottom as well'. Just to clarify, are you asking how to display tabs at the bottom of the screen at the same time as displaying tabs inside the ActionBar (at top of screen)?

Comment: I think this might be related, no?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828659/how-to-stop-actionbar-tab-navigation-to-display-as-a-spinner-when-it-gets-too-lo

Comment: @GunnarKarlsson Not exactly. I don't want to have tabs, at the bottom, but if you look in my updated question, then I am positioning the blue box to the right of the red box instead of below the red box. This is the same, that the actionbar does with the tabs, when there is room for it. What I am trying to find out, is what the criteria is for this to happen with the actionbar, so I can replicate it in my red and blue box at the bottom of the screen.  I hope this helps to clear it up a bit.

Comment: @Raanan I'm afraid, I cannot see how that question relates to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ActionBarSherlock** which, I believe, replicates native ActionBar's behavior checks `R.bool.abs__action_bar_embed_tabs` resource. And this resource is `true` only for `values-w480` configuration.

Comment: That is exactly what, I was looking for. Maybe I can check this boolean resource to make sure it works even if they change this later on. For now, I'll go with w480 - thank you!