# Android: ActionBar tabs showing beside logo, not below it

Tags: android, android-actionbar

what I need to do is have the tab below the action bar, how is this possible? I tried following all the tutorials and even though in the tutorials' screen shots it appears to be below the action bar in my device (a Samsung Galaxy Tab) it appears beside the logo like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
public class Yab extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener{


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_yab);


    RelativeLayout custom = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    custom.setLayoutParams(params); 
    custom.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // add the custom view to the action bar
    //actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.activity_yab);

    actionBar.show();

    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(custom);

    actionBar.setTitle("Trial");
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("add")
        .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("delete")
        .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("view")
        .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("view2")
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("view3")
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("view4")
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("view5")
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("view6")
            .setTabListener(this));
    //actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
      //  | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
  }





@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

How can I move the position of the tabs to be below the action bar? Any suggestions are really appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828659/how-to-stop-actionbar-tab-navigation-to-display-as-a-spinner-when-it-gets-too-lo/13828869#13828869)

Comment: Where should I put it (<bool name="action_bar_embed_tabs">false</bool> )??
I'm kinda new to this =s

Comment: Into your values-480dp/styles.xml. You may have to create this folder and file. You also have to create a style in which you can put in these attributes.

Comment: Okay, I then need to have my actionbar use this style right? if so, how? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I'm sorry but when I try to do this: 
<style  name="ActionBarTrial">
      <bool name="action_bar_embed_tabs">false</bool>
   </style>

I get an error that <bool can only be put inside an item, and when I do put it inside an item nothing changes in the activity and the tabs are still beside the logo

Comment: Sorry I mixed something up. You don't have to put that in styles.xml. Just create a bools.xml file in values-480dp and paste those boolean values in there. Sorry.

Comment: Don't worry about it! I did what you said now but I'm afraid that it's not working either, the tabs are still beside the logo.

Comment: Hmm, like I already said in the linked post, it is intend to be this way (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24439) so this trick might not always work.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your efforts!