# actionbar tabs auto switch to list in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using using sherlockactionbar library, and there are several action bar tabs on the screen, but whenever I rotate the device to landscape mode, the tabs automatically switch to list mode.So how can I force tabs even in landscape mode?

```
public class Test1 extends BaseActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
public Test1() {
    super(R.string.test1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Search").setTabListener(this));
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("List").setTabListener(this));
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Favorites").setTabListener(this));
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of (at least) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828659/how-to-stop-actionbar-tab-navigation-to-display-as-a-spinner-when-it-gets-too-lo) and [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15533684/409349) you are looking for. At least it worked for me.

PS: I know this question is old but it should be closed anyway.