# Action Bar Tab not splitting in Landscape mode

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to display Tabs below Android Action Bar in Landscape mode

I have set

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

I tried `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in Android manifest but everything seems to be OK in Portrait. But when view changes to Landscape, the tabs get embedded inside action bar.
Anyone has implemented this, because this does not seem to work.
OS - ICS and above.

Comment: [Look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828659/how-to-stop-actionbar-tab-navigation-to-display-as-a-spinner-when-it-gets-too-lo/13828869#13828869)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behaviour. It's Split-Action-Bar-When-Narrow option and there are no options how to determine which actions will be displayed at top and which at bottom. ActionBar element is doing this according to screen orientation and screen resolution. Use your own toolbar.